# My Single Page App uses 1.8MB worth of Javascript and CSS from frameworks, is this considered bad?

Tags: single-page-application

I have made a single page app for internal use at my workplace, and it loads 1.8MB worth of Javascript and CSS from various frameworks and libraries (Such as Semantic UI, AngularJS, JQuery, RenderJS, MomentJS...etc).

I find all of these frameworks very useful, and completely necessary for a smooth single page app. However, they end up making the page load a bit slow. I understand that small size is ideal for a website, but is that as much the case for single page apps? Is it expected that a single page app would load a much larger set of CSS and Javascript?

Comment: You have to balance functionality against cost. That said, are you sure you need _all_ of the libraries you are loading? Look at each one, see how much load they add, and decide if its worth it.

Comment: Are you minimizing all the code and css?  if not, I'd certainly considering doing so.  You're using quite a few frameworks so it's not surprising your load size is fairly large.  I'm not sure what all you're attempting to do on the page, but JQuery with JQuery UI and JQuery mobile (as an example) should be able to do much of what you're wanting a single-page app to do.  I would see what you can do to pare down the frameworks you're using if size and load time are problematic right not.